# Docker containers running memory intensive processes are terminated - Exit code 1

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, amazon-eks

I am using gitlab CI to run triggered jobs on AWS K8S (EKS) and while running a long and memory/process intensive job, the container spun up to run that job gets terminated with an exit code 1.

[image: This is the error message that is shown on the gitlab console]

I looked at the logs in /var/log/messages on the worker nodes and the below logs are a minute before I got the error.

```
Feb  7 04:11:15 ip-10-226-44-109 kubelet: I0207 04:11:15.614914    4804 reconciler.go:301] Volume detached for volume "repo" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/empty-dir/b8f0c962-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662-repo") on node "ip-10-226-44-109.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal" DevicePath ""
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered blocking state
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered disabled state
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: device veth94e5db0 entered promiscuous mode
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered blocking state
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered forwarding state
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered disabled state
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: eth0: renamed from vethae08789
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered blocking state
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered forwarding state
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kubelet: W0207 04:11:16.401374    4804 kubelet_getters.go:284] Path "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/b8f0c962-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662/volumes" does not exist
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kubelet: W0207 04:11:16.401410    4804 kubelet_getters.go:284] Path "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/b9edf486-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662/volumes" does not exist
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered disabled state
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: vethae08789: renamed from eth0
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered disabled state
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: device veth94e5db0 left promiscuous mode
Feb  7 04:11:16 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth94e5db0) entered disabled state
Feb  7 04:11:59 ip-10-226-44-109 kubelet: I0207 04:11:59.379996    4804 reconciler.go:207] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "default-token-r26dz" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/secret/fc5d9f2e-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662-default-token-r26dz") pod "runner-u4zrz1by-project-12123209-concurrent-44rwnh" (UID: "fc5d9f2e-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662")
Feb  7 04:11:59 ip-10-226-44-109 kubelet: I0207 04:11:59.380025    4804 reconciler.go:207] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "repo" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/empty-dir/fc5d9f2e-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662-repo") pod "runner-u4zrz1by-project-12123209-concurrent-44rwnh" (UID: "fc5d9f2e-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662")
Feb  7 04:11:59 ip-10-226-44-109 systemd: Started Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fc5d9f2e-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-r26dz.
Feb  7 04:11:59 ip-10-226-44-109 systemd: Starting Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fc5d9f2e-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-r26dz.
Feb  7 04:11:59 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:11:59Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/1921d53d580fc451fd2801dffc196a67e2970acbfbf2604ddf96b925bb7ecb88/shim.sock" debug=false pid=24408
Feb  7 04:12:00 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:00Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/b9afda2153670e1427b562c33bd173039cea4e9adcd5433709fcdc31068fd9ff/shim.sock" debug=false pid=24533
Feb  7 04:12:00 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:00Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/c0f4dcfd74f4eb53ba486e0844bbdea82bc177084fca8faa005ef2a04e3bfaab/shim.sock" debug=false pid=24600
Feb  7 04:12:00 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:00Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/d887b7a2f86900d378c709c64c32faec99935753ff6525bf1992f1efc53cf8b4/shim.sock" debug=false pid=24668
Feb  7 04:12:00 ip-10-226-44-109 kubelet: I0207 04:12:00.481851    4804 reconciler.go:207] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "repo" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/empty-dir/fcff51c0-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662-repo") pod "runner-u4zrz1by-project-12123209-concurrent-5tcz7v" (UID: "fcff51c0-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662")
Feb  7 04:12:00 ip-10-226-44-109 kubelet: I0207 04:12:00.481889    4804 reconciler.go:207] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "default-token-r26dz" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/secret/fcff51c0-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662-default-token-r26dz") pod "runner-u4zrz1by-project-12123209-concurrent-5tcz7v" (UID: "fcff51c0-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662")
Feb  7 04:12:00 ip-10-226-44-109 systemd: Started Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fcff51c0-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-r26dz.
Feb  7 04:12:00 ip-10-226-44-109 systemd: Starting Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fcff51c0-495f-11ea-b638-0673fa95f662/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-r26dz.
Feb  7 04:12:00 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:00Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/1c6ce43191ef995ceab9d237327071b6b8e7a57165f458c9f11960d51e47a07e/shim.sock" debug=false pid=24798
Feb  7 04:12:00 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:00Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/d15361ee161d0c66bf02a8e009f0d8441608b372a3d0b1f305c5b6bb2cc0f12a/shim.sock" debug=false pid=24977
Feb  7 04:12:01 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:01Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/53baa9364337b3d3bbd7fff3606fc985ed20586c293bf9a28e353f48474e8085/shim.sock" debug=false pid=25203
Feb  7 04:12:01 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:01Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/962a39cfda64405c73872a5d5945dea879aa87873d088925edf600b6f1b6b321/shim.sock" debug=false pid=25269
Feb  7 04:12:01 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:01Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/cc4ef0c7f4c512033c55888770a0477d1a1afa02b7d9611adaa0a03b3388a6ba/shim.sock" debug=false pid=25340
Feb  7 04:12:01 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:01Z" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/4d871dc03e766baa5707c0bd6502c24333aab9263d52443d31e19ac080054d9d/shim.sock" debug=false pid=25463
Feb  7 04:12:05 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:05Z" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=28b82bf41cfa344d616118007a8b9ac2440148b65dd76afb4124504c404e65a8
Feb  7 04:12:05 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:05.663819264Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06Z" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=3dab6902724b6639dfbcb5b546eb9b9e8f3131ac5d63453303955d8412f9e23b
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06.475126364Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06.590951867Z" level=info msg="Container 245af759c17645d8fbad6fa86c83812aaf109db19a6271037bfdc2ddec1975c2 failed to exit within 2 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06.590959536Z" level=info msg="Container 7a21f68defc90bacdd8db3bc2660d18b06801f4ea312befef01e8eb95d115d3b failed to exit within 2 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06.598126562Z" level=info msg="Container 7a21f68defc90bacdd8db3bc2660d18b06801f4ea312befef01e8eb95d115d3b failed to exit within 2 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06.600480653Z" level=info msg="Container 245af759c17645d8fbad6fa86c83812aaf109db19a6271037bfdc2ddec1975c2 failed to exit within 2 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06Z" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=7a21f68defc90bacdd8db3bc2660d18b06801f4ea312befef01e8eb95d115d3b
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06.680421611Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06Z" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=245af759c17645d8fbad6fa86c83812aaf109db19a6271037bfdc2ddec1975c2
Feb  7 04:12:06 ip-10-226-44-109 dockerd: time="2020-02-07T04:12:06.692681358Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
```

What I did notice is that whenever a process is being terminated, I can see the below in the log:

```
Feb 10 01:30:42 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth81ae14c) entered disabled state
Feb 10 01:30:42 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: veth59985b4: renamed from eth0
Feb 10 01:30:42 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth81ae14c) entered disabled state
Feb 10 01:30:42 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: device veth81ae14c left promiscuous mode
Feb 10 01:30:42 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth81ae14c) entered disabled state
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethab14b48) entered disabled state
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: veth43de279: renamed from eth0
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethab14b48) entered disabled state
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: device vethab14b48 left promiscuous mode
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(vethab14b48) entered disabled state
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9b33ebc) entered blocking state
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9b33ebc) entered disabled state
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: device veth9b33ebc entered promiscuous mode
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9b33ebc) entered blocking state
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9b33ebc) entered forwarding state
Feb 10 01:30:43 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9b33ebc) entered disabled state
Feb 10 01:30:44 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: eth0: renamed from veth61422d0
Feb 10 01:30:44 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9b33ebc) entered blocking state
Feb 10 01:30:44 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9b33ebc) entered forwarding state
Feb 10 01:30:44 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9b33ebc) entered disabled state
Feb 10 01:30:44 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: veth61422d0: renamed from eth0
Feb 10 01:30:44 ip-10-226-44-109 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9b33ebc) entered disabled state
```

Could anyone help me understand the reason for this and a potential solution?

Thank you.

Comment: can you check if there is any defined resource quota in the name space you are using `$ kubectl describe namespaces <yournamespace>` .. what are resource limits defined on your job !!

Comment: Hello @DT. No, there are no quotas defined for the namespaces. I did not want to apply any quotas or limitranges for the namespaces in which gitlab runners are being spun up as they can get pretty resource hungry depending on the job.